# kivy not adding/placing widgets properly when adding in for-loop

Tags: python, kivy

I want to place 6 blocks (widgets) to the screen. I first update the 'pos' attributes of the blocks and then try to add them one by one to the screen. The problem is that the last block is not placed at all and all the others are in their neighbors position instead of the one given to them.

I have tried multiple variations like setting the positions at initialization with kwarg, didn't work. Seems I don't get something so I ask for help. Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

```py
class Block(Widget):

    def __init__(self, red, green, blue, **kwargs):
        super(Block, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.canvas.add(Color(red, green, blue, 1))


class GameEnvironment(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameEnvironment, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.blocks = self.create_blocks()
        self.position_blocks()
        self.add_blocks()

    def create_blocks(self):
        red_block = Block(1, 0, 0)
        blue_block = Block(0, 0, 1)
        green_block = Block(0, 1, 0)
        black_block = Block(0, 0, 0)
        orange_block = Block(1, .55, 0)
        celeste_block = Block(.5, 1, .83)
        return [red_block, blue_block, green_block, black_block, orange_block, celeste_block]

    def position_blocks(self):
        x = 0
        for block in self.blocks:
            block.pos = [x, 0]
            print("position:", block.pos)
            x += 100


    def add_blocks(self):
        for block in self.blocks:
            print("drawing block")
            self.add_widget(block)

class BlocksGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game_environment = GameEnvironment()
        return game_environment


BlocksGameApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
<GameEnvironment>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Block>:
    width: 100
    height: self.width
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Expected: 6 rectangles next to each other with red in left bottom corner.

Result: 5 rectangles with the first at position 100, 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1

> So the color is added after the group but why aren't all the
>   rectangles white then?

## Notes

The word, ***group*** means graphics instructions such as *Color, Rectangles, Triangles, Lines, Ellipse* and so on.

### Answer 1

With reference to this app, the process of the constructor is broken down into two steps.

#### Step 1: Instantiation - Block(...)

When each block is instantiated, it has a template with graphics instruction of `Rectangle`, which makes up a group.

Modal View

```
Block:
    width: 100
    height: self.width
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

#### Step 2: Add Color(...)

After instantiated a block, the next graphics instruction added to the group is `Color`. When the keyword, `after` or `before` is omitted from `canvas`, it applies the default, `after`.

Modal View

```
Block:
    width: 100
    height: self.width
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red colour
```

#### Summary

Therefore, all the blocks are not white colour because `Color` instruction was added after the group, `Rectangle`. The first block is white colour because the last `Color` instruction executed came from the root widget, `GameEnvironment`. 
The second block is red colour because the previous `Color` instruction executed was red. The third block is blue colour because the previous `Color` instruction executed was blue, and so on.

The following example illustrates the equivalent of your program except the background colour is black, each block is added manually, and the default size of a widget is 100 by 100 (`size: 100, 100`, or `size_hint: 1, 1`).

#### canvas.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
Widget:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1    # black background colour 
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size       

    Widget:
        pos: 0, 0
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red colour

    Widget:
        pos: 100, 0
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1    # blue colour

    Widget:
        pos: 200, 0
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1    # green colour

    Widget:
        pos: 300, 0
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1    # black colour

    Widget:
        pos: 400, 0
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0.55, 0, 1    # orange colour

    Widget:
        pos: 500, 0
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgba: 0.5, 1, 0.83, 1    # celeste colour

"""))
```

#### Answer 1 Demo

[image: canvas without before]

## Question 2

> Isn't the color added to each block object itself?

### Answer 2

The graphics instruction, `Color` is added to each block object but the colour does not applied immediately because the keyword, `before` was omitted from `canvas`, it applies the default, `after`.

Therefore, the colour is applied to the next instantiated widget, if and only if that widget does not have the graphics instruction, `Color` specified.

## Problem

> the last block is not placed at all and all the others are in their
>   neighbors position instead of the one given to them

### Root Cause

Running your app, did indeed added 6 blocks. But the first block is white colour because the last `Color` instruction executed came from the root widget, `GameEnvironment`. The second block is red. The third block is blue, and so on. The `Color` is added [`after`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas.after) the group.

### Solution

Add the keyword, `before` to `self.canvas.add(Color(...))`

#### Snippets

```
class Block(Widget):

    def __init__(self, red, green, blue, **kwargs):
        super(Block, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.canvas.before.add(Color(red, green, blue, 1))
```

### [Kivy Canvas » before](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas.before)

> ```
> before
> ```
>
> Property for getting the ‘before’ group.

### Output

[image: Result]

Comment: This solved it, thanks. Follow up question: So the color is added after the group but why aren't all the rectangles white then? Isn't the color added to each block object itself? It seems a bit confusing that one block object gets a color that was added to a different object.

Comment: Thanks alot! Good explanation!

Comment: You are most welcome! Please feel free to up-vote my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `Color` to a `Canvas` adds it after the `Rectangle`, so it doesn't affect the current `Rectangle`. Instead, add a `Color` to the `Block` in the `kv` as:

```
<Block>:
    width: 100
    height: self.width
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.r, self.g, self.b, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Then add `r`, `g`, and `b` properties to the `Block` class:

```
class Block(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1)
    g = NumericProperty(1)
    b = NumericProperty(1)

    def __init__(self, red, green, blue, **kwargs):
        super(Block, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.r = red
        self.g = green
        self.b = blue
```

I think that will fix it.